# Matlab applying homography to an set of points (not an image)

Tags: matlab, transformation, homography

what I'm trying to do is applying an given homography to an set of points (x,y) (instead of the usual use case of applying it to images.)

I have a homography stored as a 3x3 dimensional matrix:

```
H =
    1.06  -0.56  77.55
   -0.02   0.74  28.34
    0.02  -0.01   1.00
```

and I have a set of points. E.g.:

```
pts = [x1,y1 ; x2,y2 ; x3,y3 ;x4,y4 ; ...];
```

How can I apply `H` to `pts` ?

I know for applying it to an image its fairly simple like:

```
img = imread('pathtofile\file.png');
tform = projective2d(H); 
img2 = imwarp(img, tform);
```

But is there an equivalent of `imwrap` for a pointlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`transformPointsForward`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/projective2d.transformpointsforward.html) function that's part of the `projective2d` class.  However, note that the homography you have specified assumes that you are pre-multiplying the homography with the input points.  This is apparent because the last column looks like the translation vector.  That is, given the matrix `H` and a matrix of points `P` where each **column** is one point in augmented form where there is a third row with the value of 1, you can achieve the warping of the points in the following way:

```
out = H * P;
```

You will finally get the warped points - one point per column.  Note that the coordinates are in **homogeneous** form, so you must take the third coordinate and divide the corresponding first and second values in each column by their third coordinate.

```
out(1,:) = out(1,:) ./ out(3,:);
out(2,:) = out(2,:) ./ out(3,:);
out = out(1:2,:);
```

However, using `transformPointsForward` assumes that you are **post-multiplying** with the matrix, and so you must transpose the homography matrix.  This is due to MATLAB's column-major preference and so the coefficients of the homography matrix are read out in column-major order.  However, you can leave the points matrix intact.

As such when you specify the homography `H`, you must **transpose** it first prior to creating the `projective2d` instance.  Once you do that, you can use `transformPointsForward`.

```
tform = projective2d(H.');
out = transformPointsForward(tform, pts);
```

The first input to the function would be the projective transform you created, and the second input is a matrix of points - one per line.  The output would be a matrix that is the same size as `pts` but with each row being the transformed version of each input point given `tform`.

However, you can achieve the same thing yourself without `transformPointsForward` if you'd like to figure out how this is done under the hood.  This is done by first transposing `pts`, augmenting it with a row vector of `ones`, multiplying with `H` then transposing the result to be of the same size.  However, you should note that these warped coordinates are in homogeneous form, so you will have to do the division like we specified before:

```
pts_aug = [pts.'; ones(1, size(pts, 1))];
out = (H * pts_aug).';
out = bsxfun(@rdivide, out(:,1:2), out(:,3));
```

The first line performs the augmentation, the second line does the warping and finally the third line does the division that we talked about.  I decided to use `bsxfun` to do the division in one line.  However in MATLAB R2016b and onwards, we can take advantage of broadcasting:

```
out = out(:,1:2) ./ out(:,3);
```

---

As a quick example, let's define your `H` in MATLAB, then let's define a bunch of random points:

```
H =[1.06  -0.56  77.55; -0.02   0.74  28.34; 0.02  -0.01   1.00];
rng(123);
pts = randi(20, 4, 2);
```

We define `H` as the homography, and I seed the random generator so that we generate four 2D random points where the maximum value expected is 20.  One row is one point like you specified in your question.  Now let's make sure that this behaviour is consistent between the two methods:

```
% Method #1
tform = projective2d(H.');
out = transformPointsForward(tform, pts);

% Method #2
pts_aug = [pts.'; ones(1, size(pts, 1))];
out2 = (H * pts_aug).';
out2 = bsxfun(@rdivide, out2(:,1:2), out2(:,3));
```

`out` and `out2` are the output warped points, and displaying them we get:

```
>> format long g
>> out

out =

          74.3274336283186          34.6548672566372
          76.5728155339806          33.8640776699029
          79.6111111111111          47.8222222222222
          74.9363636363636          34.9636363636364

>> out2

out2 =

          74.3274336283186          34.6548672566372
          76.5728155339806          33.8640776699029
          79.6111111111111          47.8222222222222
          74.9363636363636          34.9636363636364
```

Comment: would be great if you add the looping over the point list as well (in oder to transform every point). This was a bit challenging for me. But the 1st approach is working great. But for some reason the 2nd not (but one is enough ^^). Thx for the detailed explanation

Comment: Hi. Both codes loop over every point. Could you elaborate? Why didn't the second one work?